# Mapping a list of type string to a list of objects with a string property using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Here is my scenario. I have a class, Class1, with a property of type string[]

```
Class Class1
{
    string[] strings{ get; set;}
}
```

and I want to map each string in the list to a string property within a list of type MyClass.

```
Class MyClass
{
    string someString { get; set;]
}
```

So, using automapper it would be something like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, IEnumerable<MyClass>>().ForMember(dest => dest.someString, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.strings));
```

I know this won't work but I would imagine it would be something list this.
I am not really sure where to go from here or if it is even possible any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this:

1. Use `ConstructUsing` along with some LINQ:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
       .ConstructUsing(
           src => src.strings.Select(str => new MyClass { someString = str }));
   ```
2. Use an "inner" mapping from `string` to `MyClass` and call *that* from `ConstructUsing`:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<string, MyClass>()
       .ConstructUsing(str => new MyClass { someString = str });

   Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
       .ConstructUsing(src => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(src.strings));
   ```

*Update based on comments*:

If you have multiple `string[]` properties in the source class and multiple corresponding `string` properties in the destination class, you could do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
    .ConstructUsing(
        src => src.strings
            .Zip(src.strings2, (str1, str2) => new { str1, str2 })
            .Zip(src.strings3, (res1, str3) => 
                new MyClass 
                { 
                    someString = res1.str1,
                    someString2 = res1.str2, 
                    someString3 = str3
                }));
```

You'd basically call `.Zip` as many times as you have to. This assumes all of the indexes match up for each array and the number of elements in each array is the same.

Comment: As a follow up, how would you do this with multiple properties in the same class?

Comment: In the source or destination? If you update your question I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: The source, class1, contains n properties of type string[] and I want to map them into a list of MyClass that contains n properties of type string. I solved it with a custom resolver but I feel like this can  be done without doing that.

Comment: @Chris: I updated my answer. If the number of properties is huge, you might want to look into a custom resolver instead